# How to set ListItem height equals to ListView height inside a ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I wonder if it is possible to set the listitem height equals to listview height in the getView method of a ArrayAdapter.

How can I accomplish this task? Thank you.

Comment: For what purpose you need this functionality

Comment: I have a vertical list view and I want to each list item fills the screen. I am also trying that the list items snap to the list view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runnable fitsOnScreen = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int last = invitelist.getLastVisiblePosition();
            if(last < invitelist.getCount()-1) 
                // if(last == invitelist.getCount() - 1 && invitelist.getChildAt(last).getBottom() <= invitelist.getHeight())
            {

                invitelist.setFastScrollEnabled(true) ;
                invitelist.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);

            }else {
                invitelist.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
                invitelist.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(false);

            }

        }
    };
```

yourlistView.post(fitsOnScreen);

it will automatically set the listitem height equals to listview height in the getView method of a ArrayAdapter.

Or u can use the following .

```
//package com.omareitti;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Utils {

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }

        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }



}
```

Comment: within class of where you are using  listview... or add it after onCreate() Method

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I don't know where the list item item height is set equals to the list view height.

Comment: when listview items are greater to fit on screen it will automatically add scroll view and if less then automatically no scroll view will be shown.My answer fullfil your this requirement " 
I have a vertical list view and I want to each list item fills the screen. I am also trying that the list items snap to the list view"

Comment: Thanks but what I want is set the list item height equals to the list view height. This is not happening with this code.

Comment: Hey @Umer. Now it seems to be working. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I think I already did before you asked because I think it was helpful. I accepted the answer and I marked as helpful. Do you mind to mark the question as useful too?